# Take a photo then attach to email

Tags: android

I am trying to take a photo then attach this to email

This is my code:

```
Intent chupanh = new Intent();
    chupanh.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    File photoFile = null;
    try {
        photoFile = makephotofile();
    } catch (IOException ae) {
        ae.printStackTrace();
    }


    Uri urianh = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
    chupanh.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, urianh);
    startActivityForResult(chupanh, Code_request);
```

Code to send image with intent

```
    Intent emailz = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:"
            + "osaka@gmail.com"));
    emailz.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
    emailz.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text");

    File anhfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), fileplace);

    fileUri = Uri.fromFile(anhfile);
    emailz.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
    //
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailz, "send email"));
```

But this only send a photo name.

what should i do to fix it?

thanks.

Comment: please check that are you sending correct image uri

Comment: if uri is not correct  or null then this will not consider

Comment: thanks for editing. when i click to capture then i don understand where's image link. i think this 's my problem